How can I rearrange lines of text with regular expression search-and-replace?
I have a log file containing timestamps and usernames on our service from 6+ years ago. The issue lies in the fact that the new system won't accept any logs from 3+ years ago without some heavy editing.
The items are formatted like this:
[2018/01/21 13:51] UsernameHere: I sent this message, which doesn't affect the ability to input the contents into the system.

I need to make them be formatted like this:
UsernameHere — 2018/01/21 1:51 PM
I sent this message, which doesn't affect the ability to input the contents into the system.

I tried using the Regex Match feature to match:
\[2018\/[01][0-9]\/[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]\] UsernameHere

And replace with:
UsernameHere — 2018\/[01][0-9]\/[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9](\r)(\n)

But doing so results in the text outputting exactly as the replace bar says rather than applying the regex in reverse and keeping the original text within the date portion intact.
Any help shifting the names to the front would be much appreciated. I will likely make a separate post requesting help with the timestamp details (24-hour to 12-hour) once this first problem is solved.
Addendum: I asked the question with seconds in the formatting, not realizing that typing an example by hand was bound to lead to user error. I also lack almost any knowledge in any coding languages, so using a separate program to edit the timestamps using code is sadly not an option for me. Finally, I wanted to make it clear that the hyphen between the username and the timestamp in the result I wanted to achieve is actually U+2014 (The Em Dash) and not a standard hyphen, hence why I've not used the backslash to negate it.

You need to use capture groups. Your example seems a bit over-specific about the date format too. Example: https://regex101.com/r/J9F2zf/1 -- note that your current matching pattern is using - separators in the date, which does not match your data (which uses /) at all. If you want to generate the AM/PM then you'll need to do two passes over the data with different expressions to translate 24-hour time.

You can build the new string from the contents of four capture groups obtained by matching the regular expression ^\[(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})( \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\] ([a-zA-Z]+): (.+), as shown here . This does not convert the time from a 24-hour clock to a 12-hour clock, with "AM" and "PM"; you will have to do that in code.

@paddy You're right, I accidentally used dashes, and didn't catch it right away. I hope it's not too late to make an edit now. (For clarification, I retyped the regex by hand when making this post, so it was inaccurate due to that.)

Ouch. Just realized I also did the date format with seconds in the post when typing the example, and now the three answers are inaccurate.

@SamHammie Try the expression that I have edited into my answer. It's horrible, but it works and does close to what you want... It doesn't remove leading zeroes from the hour, but that could be done.

You have not used any capture groups in your expression, so there's no way to specify what matched text should be used in the substitution. It's a good idea to review the Notepad++ documentation on regular expressions: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions
Try something simpler to begin with, by not caring about the timestamp format -- just match everything in square brackets:
[i am a timestamp] paddy: hello world

For this, you would do:

match: ^\[(.+)\] (\w+):\s*
replace: $2 - $1\n

This would result in:
paddy - i am a timestamp
hello world

Basically, things enclosed in parentheses are matching groups. They are numbered. You can see how those numbered groups are substituted into the replacement. The ^ matches from the start of the line. We don't need to match the entire line -- just the stuff that you want to modify.
You can name them if you like:

match: ^\[(?<time>[0-9\/]+ \d\d:\d\d)] (?<user>\w+):\s*
replace: $user - $time\n

This is still matching the date naively, and the time for that matter. But you can make it complicated if you want. The capture groups are named to make life easier, especially if you start adding extra submatch groups.
As for the timestamp 24-hour to 12-hour conversion, this is actually not so easy to do because it requires doing math on a subgroup match, which is not supported by regular expressions. For something like this, you may be better off using Awk or Perl, or whatever your favorite language is.
You can do it with Notepad++ regular expressions, using Substitution conditionals. But I think the expression would become stupidly complicated. This just isn't really the tool for that job.

And for fun, I did create a full expression to translate your log files. Here's what I came up with, in all its horrendous glory...
The expression:
^\[(?<date>\d{4}\/\d\d\/\d\d) ((?<pm>1((?<h12>2)|(?<h1>3)|(?<h2>4)|(?<h3>5)|(?<h4>6)|(?<h5>7)|(?<h6>8)|(?<h7>9))|2((?<h8>0)|(?<h9>1)|(?<h10>2)|(?<h11>3)))|(?<hh>0[1-9]|1[01])|(?<h0>00)):(?<mm>\d\d)\] (?<user>\w+)

The replacement:
$+{user} - $+{date} (?{h0}12)(?{h1}01)(?{h2}02)(?{h3}03)(?{h4}04)(?{h5}05)(?{h6}06)(?{h7}07)(?{h8}08)(?{h9}09)(?{h10}10)(?{h11}11)(?{h12}12)$+{hh}:$+{mm} (?{pm}PM:AM)\n

A structured breakdown of the grouping makes it a bit clearer what's happening:
^\[(?<date>\d{4}\/\d\d\/\d\d)
   (
     (?<pm>
       1(
         (?<h12>2)|
         (?<h1>3)|
         (?<h2>4)|
         (?<h3>5)|
         (?<h4>6)|
         (?<h5>7)|
         (?<h6>8)|
         (?<h7>9)
       )|
       2(
         (?<h8>0)|
         (?<h9>1)|
         (?<h10>2)|
         (?<h11>3)
       )
     )|
     (?<hh>
       0[1-9]|
       1[01]
     )|
     (?<h0>00)
   ):(?<mm>\d\d)\] (?<user>\w+)

The hours 12-23 are all in the group named pm, and each individual PM-hour is named h12, h1, h2, h3 ...  h11. The AM-hours 01-11 are named hh, and midnight is h0. The rest of the timestamp is stored as date and mm
The replacement string then selects all the various hours and outputs the correct values.
I tested this successfully on the following input:
[2018/01/21 00:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 01:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 02:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 03:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 04:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 05:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 06:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 07:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 08:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 09:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 09:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 10:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 11:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 12:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 13:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 14:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 15:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 16:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 17:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 18:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 19:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 20:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 21:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 22:00] username: message
[2018/01/21 23:00] username: message

Suffice to say, this is horrible! It's a good argument for learning a language like Awk or Perl, or even Python. That would have been actually easier.
Developing an expression like this can take a bit trial and error, and a lot of patience. If you mess up, introduce a typo or mismatch a parenthesis somewhere, it's not fun to figure out what happened. You need a decent regex editor to help with that. You would not want to just develop it in the Notepad++ search box.

"As for the timestamp 24-hour to 12-hour conversion, this is actually not so easy to do because..." is the understatement of the day.

haha never say never!

For "stupidly complicated" please see this answer of mine about converting AM/PM times to 24-hour clock.

@AdrianHHH That doesn't translate hours 13-24 into hours 1-12, which is what I was talking about. However, that can also be done with conditionals, but it's ugly. My general rule is that when an expression becomes ridiculous, time is better spent finding a different way. A bunch of manual search-and-replace for each hour might be more efficient use of time than concocting the perfect expression.

Agreed. I was pointing out that the reverse translation is possible and is a candidate for the "stupidly complicated" mentioned in your answer. I think the 24-hour to AM/PM conversion could be done in a similar manner but it will be complicated.

Well, I created one and edited accordingly. I'm not proud of it. I think nobody should use regular expressions like this.

"Replace All: 0 occurrences were replaced in entire file" - are you sure this matches up now? It should match any date - I used 2018/01/21 as an example.

The expression and replacement that I show here is working on the example data that I showed, in the latest version of Notepad++.  Did you try that? I don't know what else you're doing. Perhaps your data is not actually formatted similar to the example. Don't use the "expanded" version of the expression -- that was laid out for illustrative purposes only, and will not work.

You might use a conditional replacement for AM or PM depending on the 24h notation. If I am not mistaken, you can not do math using conditional replacements to like converting 13:51:23 to 1:51 PM.
\[(\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}\h+)(?:(?<am>(?:0\d|1[0-1]):[0-5][0-9])|(?<pm>(?:1[2-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])):\d{1,2}]\h+([^:\s]+):\h+(.+)

The pattern in parts:

\[ Match [
(\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}\h+) Capture group 1, match a date like pattern and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
(?: Non capture group for the 2 alternatives

(?<am> Named capture group for am

(?:0\d|1[0-1]) Match hours 00 - 11
: Match literally
[0-5][0-9] Match minutes 00 - 59


) Close group am
| Or
(?<pm> Named caputure group pm

(?:1[2-9]|2[0-3]) Match hours 12 - 23
:
[0-5][0-9] Match minutes 00 - 59


) Close group pm


) Close the outer non capture group
: Match literally
\d{1,2}]\h+ Match 1-2 digits, ] and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
([^:\s]+) Capture group 4, match 1+ non whitespace characters except for :
: Match literally
\h+ Match 1+ horizontal whitespace characters
(.+) Capture group 5, match 1+ times any character

In the replacement use:
$4 - $1(?{am}$2 AM:$3 PM)\n$5



Find:
^\[([^\]]+)\] ([^:]+): (.*)$

Replace:
$2 — $1\n$3

Then need to convert the timestamp format with a programming language because regex can't do that.
